# Why does `(( 0 ))` have a return value of 1 in .sh script?

Tags: bash, shell, sh

```
> [ 0 ]; echo $?
0
> [[ 0 ]]; echo $?
0
> (( 0 )); echo $?
1
> [ 1 ]; echo $?
0
> [[ 1 ]]; echo $?
0
> (( 1 )); echo $?
0
```

Is the behavior of `(( 0 ))` just to match the typical numerical value of false in other languages? IE where `true == 1` and `false == 0`?

Comment: If this weren't true, it would have some very unintuitive effects. In the case of `if (( foo )); then do_something; fi`, folks expect `do_something` to be run for positive values of `foo`, not for zero.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy What about `if some_function; then do_something; fi`? Do folks expect `do_something` to be run when `some_function` returns positive values? It's not as obvious to newcomers as you comment implies.

Comment: @P.P., eh? Exact same rules apply for functions as for every other command's exit status (including external commands). The only distinction that needs to be internalized is between *exit status* and *numerical value* (in an arithmetic context).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Conditional-Constructs.html#Conditional-Constructs):

> `(( expression ))`
>   The arithmetic *expression* is evaluated according to the rules described below (see Shell Arithmetic). If the value of the *expression* is non-zero, the return status is `0`; otherwise the return status is `1`.

Your supposition is probably right, that it's to mimic the way many programming languages treat any non-zero value as truthy. You can then write:

```
if (( <expression> ))
then
    ...
fi
```

similar to how you would do it in C.

Answer (score 2):

Barmar already gave the right reply for your main question.

A large part of your tests weren't about testing an arithmetic expressions value though but related to the `test` command `[` or the `ksh`/`bash` conditional compound command `[[`.

In that case, if there is no operator, the test is string based, not arithmetic and the rule is very simple, everything not an empty string evaluates to true so only the empty string evaluates to false.

That's the reason all of your non arithmetic tests return a success status (0):

```
$ [ 0 ]; echo $?
0
$ [[ 0 ]]; echo $?
0
$ [ 1 ]; echo $?
0
$ [[ 1 ]]; echo $?
0
```

To get a failure status (1):

```
$ [ "" ]; echo $?
1
$ [[ "" ]]; echo $?
1
```

The test command accepts no string at all too:

```
$ [ ]; echo $?
1
```

but in that case the `[[` command fails with both `bash` and `ksh`:

```
$ bash
$ [[ ]]; echo $?
bash: syntax error near ';'
$ ksh
$ [[ ]]; echo $?
ksh: syntax error: `;' unexpected
```

Comment: He's not asking about the `test` command, he's asking about `(( 1 ))`.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, fixed. Thx

Comment: Hmm. I'm not able to reproduce the syntax error with `[[ "" ]]; echo $?` you're describing here. Is that in POSIX mode?